# How to pass values back to a fragment in Navigation architectire component?

Tags: android, navigation, fragment

Suppose I have an obj of a class in Fragment A and passed it to Fragment B.
When the up button (back button) is clicked I want the same object to be passed back.

I can get to know when the up button (back button) is being clicked and get to know the
Fragment name. But sending back the params doesn't work.
It shows student val is missing and does not have defaultValue.
When I give default value it then gives error too many arguments supplied for public open fun
fragmentBTofragnentA

Here is the code below.

override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {

```
val navController = this.findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
Log.d("Up button", "Main activity")

val id = navController.currentDestination!!.id
Log.d("Now id is: ", "${id.toString()}")

val label = navController.currentDestination!!.label
Log.d("Now id is: ", "${label.toString()}")

if (label == "FragmentB") {
    navController.navigate(FragmentBDirections.actionFragmentBToFragmentA(
        obj
    )
    return false
}

return navController.navigateUp()
```

navigation file

```
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdatapassings.FragmentA"
        android:label="FragmentA">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragnentB"
            app:destination="@+id/fragmentB" />
        <argument android:name="student"
            app:argType="com.example.StudentWork.Student" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.fragmentdatapassings.FragmentB"
        android:label="FragmentB">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentB_to_fragnentA"
            app:destination="@+id/fragmentA" />
        <argument android:name="student"
            app:argType="com.example.StudentWork.Student" />
    </fragment>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're trying to share an object back and forth that way instead of using the [API for returning a result](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result)?

Comment: I have a spinner in my first fragment, what is selected I want to save it and when user from 2nd fragment goes back I want that to be displayed out of all

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use methods, setFragmentResult and setFragmentResultListener, under FragmentMananger class.
I think these methods may solve your problem.
There is an example in official guide,
https://developer.android.google.cn/training/basics/fragments/pass-data-between#java.
Hope this could help you.

Comment: It needs to add dependency `fragment:1.3.0 - alpha04` or above.